# NGINX as a reverse proxy breaks cloud sync ability

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I did my best to research this and found a few solutions that I will outline, but sadly none of them work. We have one public IP address that serves multiple servers. To make things easy we have several subdomains pointed at this IP, my example will cover cloud.example.com and noc.example.com.

NGINX is installed on what is essentially our DMZ machine, all http and https traffic is directed at this machine, we will call 10.0.1.20 and the cloud server which we will call 10.0.1.21. So I setup the reverse proxies to look like this

```
server {
listen          10.0.1.20:443
server_name     cloud.example.com;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/cloud.log  main;

include /etc/nginx/whitelist.conf;
deny all;

root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
location / {
        proxy_pass        https://10.0.1.21:443;
        proxy_set_header  Host cloud.example.com;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}}
```

and then our network monitoring software which we will call 10.0.1.22 was setup the same way but with a different proxy_set_header and a different server_name and access_log. This failed to work, for some weird reason the cloud.example.com was working fairly well, but noc.example.com would load without any form of CSS formatting and if we tried to click a link to like noc.example.com/intrusion_detect it failed.

So I dug for a few days and found a past that said I needed to change the way the location was setup and I needed to add a regex, they suggested copy and paste theirs. Looking at it the code did not seem to be malicious (4-6 characters) so I did as they suggested and the new proxies looked like this:

```
server {
listen          10.0.1.20:443;
server_name     cloud.example.com;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/cloud.log  main;

include /etc/nginx/whitelist.conf;
deny all;

root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass        http://10.0.1.21:443/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header  Host cloud.example.com;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}}
```

So adding the **~ ^/(.*)$** and the **/$1$is_args$args** seemingly fixed the styling issue but each time a client either remote or local tries to sync there are tons of errors. If I keep just the cloud.example.com proxy then the sync is fine, but add ANY other proxy on 443 and suddenly it starts failing again. The most issue I get is that the request is too big or "server response: Bad Request" which I take to be an HTTP/400 error. I am new to NGINX and reverse proxy, can anyone help me understand what I did wrong? If I missed an article online, please feel free to point me in that direction. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If it helps I have found that when direct connecting internally everything is fine and I can upload any file. When uploading externally through the NGINX Revers Proxy public URL I found that an error is logged in NGINX

Comment: SourceIP - - [03/Jan/2018:12:05:44 -0600] "PUT /remote.php/webdav/IP%20Assignments.xlsx HTTP/1.1" 400 226 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" "-"